# Type.InvokeMember - DISP_E_MEMBERNOTFOUND

Tags: c#, types, com-interop

Type.InvokeMember is failing with error cannot find member DISP_E_MEMBERNOTFOUND despite the member being very definitely there.

The `Microsoft Scripting Runtime` familiar to VB script writers has a Dictionary class but I am failing to run a simple late bound call.  Here is MCRE.  I have yet to start marshalling the return argument.

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Type type = Type.GetTypeFromProgID("Scripting.Dictionary");
        Object com_obj = Activator.CreateInstance(type);

        Object[] countArgs = new Object[1];
        string msg;
        BindingFlags invokeAttr = BindingFlags.InvokeMethod;
        try
        {

            type.InvokeMember("Count", invokeAttr, null, com_obj, null);
        }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            msg = ex.Message + ":" + ex.InnerException.Message;
            Debug.WriteLine(msg);
        }


        Console.ReadKey();
    }
```

Comment: You'll like `dynamic` a lot more.

Comment: @HansPassant : yeah, I know `dynamic` exists, I've got some interop ideas brewing and I needed to revise 'old school' techniques.  Thanks anyway, Hans.

Comment: Hmmkay, the future reader of this Q+A will like dynamic a lot more.

Comment: @HansPassant: Hans, I may need to emit IL at a lower level to synthesise a class at run-time.  I realise using dynamic makes the above example a two liner but can that be emitted in a synthesised method body using System.Reflection.Emit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use `BindingFlags invokeAttr = BindingFlags.GetProperty;` instead.
Alternativly you could use C#s dynamic to reduce the unreadable code to a minimum.

```
Type type = Type.GetTypeFromProgID("Scripting.Dictionary");
dynamic com_obj = Activator.CreateInstance(type);
var count = com_obj.Count;
```

Comment: It was a property. Doh!